# Как усовершенствовать random, чтобы числа выводились без повторений?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Как можно усовершенствовать random, чтобы он не выдавал одни и те же числа при проходе. к примеру если задать next(5), то он может вывести

```
4
2
2
1
2
```

А где же числа 3 и 5?

По существу, надо получить числа 1 2 3 4 5, но в случайном порядке.

Comment: @lalal вы лучше не Random усовершенствуйте, а свои знания. То, о чем вы тут спрашиваете исключительно от незнания матчасти

Comment: пора удалить вопрос!

Comment: @Shrek: или переформулировать :)

Comment: наверное, желательно переформулировать сам вопрос и заголовок. Вполне возможно что часть минусов пропадет :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Настоящий `random` вовсе не обязан выводить *все* числа подряд.

Смотрите. Допустим, он вывел 0 4 2 1. Теперь если вы можете со стопроцентной вероятностью ожидать появления тройки -- это никакой не `random`, настоящий `random` должен быть непредсказуем.

Для настоящего `random`'a вырабатываемое значение никак не зависит от предыдущего, так что вполне может быть пять раз подряд двойка и ни одного -- тройка. Иначе он был бы *предсказуем*, то есть нифига не случаен.

Если для вашей задачи нужно, чтобы порядок был случайным, но числа не повторялись и каждое встречалось ровно по разу, вам нужно не случайное число, а случайная перестановка. Её можно сгенерировать при помощи, например, [вот этого](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) метода. (Там и код есть.)

```
int[] perm = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray(); // 0 1 2 ... (n - 1)
Random r = <some global random instance>; // не создавайте новый Random здесь!
                                          // а то значения будут одни и те же
for (int i = n − 1; i >= 1; i--)
{
   int j = r.Next(i + 1);
   // exchange perm[j] and perm[i]
   int temp = perm[j];
   perm[j] = perm[i];
   perm[i] = temp;
}
```

(См. [здесь](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) по поводу того, почему нужен глобальный `Random`.)

---

ЗЫ: (Для пуристов:) Да, на самом деле для рандома используются не случайные, а псевдослучайные числа, и они всё же предсказуемы, я читал третью главу Кнута.

ЗЗЫ: Если вы пишете на .NET Core, можно создавать `Random()` и локально, проблема с повторяющимися последовательностями там устранена.

Comment: просто мне нужно что бы не попорядку все выдавало, но в полном составе...
пример:
числа 1 2 3 4 5
а мне надо 5 1 2 4 3

если это решимо легким способом, то прошу вас помочь

Comment: @lalal: обновил ответ

Comment: Насчет глобального рандома одно замечание: Random не является потокобезопасным. Если к нему будут одновременно обращаться несколько потоков, то корректные данные получит только один. Поэтому глобальность должна быть в контексте одного потока.

Comment: @Flammable: вы абсолютно правы, статья Джона Скита, на которую я ссылаюсь, рекомендует `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Как ни странно, этот ответ тоже не принят :)

Comment: @Flammable: @Olter уже отметил тенденцию в комментариях к вопросу :) Будем считать, что ответы для community.

Answer (score 11):

Тебе нужен не рандом, а перемешивание (shuffle, же)
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619)

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
   Random rng = new Random();  
   int n = list.Count;  
   while (n > 1) {  
       n--;  
       int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
       T value = list[k];  
       list[k] = list[n];  
       list[n] = value;  
   }  
}
```

Comment: @ESTET: а теперь сравните ваш алгоритм и алгоритм в моём ответе.

Comment: да, согласен, невнимателен

Answer (score 7):

Random.Next(5) никогда не вернет 5. Нужно прибавлять единицу к верхней границе.

Answer (score 7):

1. создай массив на N элементов и заполни его по порядку от 1 до N
2. возьми рандом от N и выбери элемент массива с этим индексом
3. удали из массива этот елемент (массив станет меньше, также уменьшится N на единицу)
4. повтори с пункта 2, пока N больше 1.
    Если создать динамический массив (тот, в котором элементы ссылаются друг на друга), то проблема удаления элемента массива исчезнет практически, иначе придётся в цикле переписывать элементы массива (пункт 3).

Comment: Великолепно. Похоже, тут будут отписываться все велосипедисты, не знающие элементарных алгоритмов?

Comment: Интересно, кстати, подумать, как такой велик будет вести себя в  плане качества случайных чисел, если, скажем для `random(n)` брать обычный `Mersenne Twister.`

Comment: @Котик: этот велосипед, на самом деле, почти равносилен [классическому алгоритму](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Там вместо удаления элемента он перемещается в конец массива.

Comment: Тогда уж добавим: перемещается в конец путем обмена с последним и последующим уменьшением размера массива.

Просто @dead (видимо оправдывая свой ник) отбросил эту очевидную оптимизацию.

Comment: не судите строго, алгоритм писался в бытность студентом под свои задачи (игра морской бой). Что это есть практически "элементарная реализация" узнал только что :)