# Как получить Random без повторения символов?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! подскажите пожалуйста как получить правильный расклад букв без повторений? например вот так: ABCD - ADBC -CBDA и т.д. что бы не было вот такого варианта: AABB - BBCC - ADBB и т.д.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
builder.append((char) ('A' + random.nextInt(4)));
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Так же вот еще пример:

```
 String alphabet = "abcd";
 int N = alphabet.length();

 Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){

        System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N))+"\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы хотите не случайные символы, а *случайную перестановку*. Это делается, например, так:

```
char[] chars = new char[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    chars[i] = (char)('A' + i);

Random r = ...  // не создавайте новый Random здесь!
                // а то значения будут одни и те же
                // заведите один общий на всю программу
for (int i = n − 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    int j = r.nextInt(i + 1);
    // exchange chars[j] and chars[i]
    char temp = chars[j];
    chars[j] = chars[i];
    chars[i] = temp;
}
String result = new String(chars);
```

---

Код честно украден из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/181206/10105).

Comment: чего то ваш код не хочет работать(((

Comment: @Andrey: А что говорит? У меня под рукой нету компилятора.

Comment: на все строки ругается

Comment: @Andrey: Вроде всё нормально: http://ideone.com/CSiHTV

Comment: вот тут вообще какой то ужас твориться 'Random r = <some global random instance>; '

Comment: а вот по той ссылке все работает 0_о

Comment: спасибо вам еще раз за ответ

Comment: @Andrey: `<some global random instance>` — это не валидный код Java, это для вас, чтобы вы не заводили `new Random` здесь, а где-то один на всю программу. Извините, если было непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Random        r = new Random();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    int num  = 4;
    int bits = 0;
    int cnt  = 0;
    while(cnt < num){
        int i  = r.nextInt(num);
        if(((bits >> i) & 1) == 1)
            continue;

        s.append((char)('A' + i));
        bits |= 1 << i;
        ++cnt;
    }

    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: спасибо за еще один ответ, но я с новыми операторами еще не знаком, в будущем пересмотрю ваш ответ.