# Проверка на случайность элементов

Tags: c#

Как проверить массив на повторяющиеся элементы и заменить их уникальными?

Comment: Зачем "проверять", если можно сразу сгенерировать случайные неповторяющиеся элементы?

Comment: @BOPOH Ну да, заменил "перебрать все перестановки последовательности элементов и найти перестанвку, в которой элементы идут по порядку" на "отсортировать"...

Comment: @Александр в цикле будет IndexOutOfRangeException потому,что i+1 больше индекса последнего елемента массива

Comment: @david_I, а заменять надо все повторяющиеся элементы или все кроме самого первого? Т.е. в массиве два элемента: [2, 2] - надо менять его на [1,3] или можно заменить на [2, 1]? Если менять все элементы, то что будет, если из массива [2, 2, 3, 3] я получу массив [1, 3, 2, 4]? Т.е. заменил все повторяющиеся элементы, но при этом заменил на другие повторяющиеся (которые, правда, сейчас встречаются всего один раз)?

Comment: @Discord, нет, не так. "отсортировать" как раз и являлось бы решением, т.к. отсортировав вы нашли бы такую перестановку автоматически. Но здесь же проблема в другом: надо по данному элементу X проверить, что ранее этот X не встречался. Т.е. это требуется выполнить и в исходной, и в вашей задаче

Comment: @BOPOH,в массиве должны быть только уникальные елементы.

Comment: @david_I, а менять не дубликаты можно? т.е. если просто сгенерировать массив чисел от 1 до n - вас это устроит? Ведь каждый элемент тогда будет уникальным )

Comment: @BOPOH думаешь я не додумался

Comment: @BOPOH   int a=r.next(1000) прописывать?

Comment: Судя по всему, вам нужен random shuffle (случайная перестановка). Например отсюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/181206/10105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если действительно все равно чем заменять дубликаты, то можно сгенерировать источник элементов, которых нет в массиве. Потом пройтись по массиву, запоминая посещенные элементы, и заменяя дубликаты. Примерно так:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 3, 2 };
var newElementsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length * 2)
    .Except(arr).GetEnumerator();

HashSet<int> knownElements = new HashSet<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    int el = arr[i];

    if (!knownElements.Add(el))
    {
        arr[i] = newElementsSource.Current;
        newElementsSource.MoveNext();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: пасиб за помощь

Answer (score 3):

> Как проверить массив на повторяющиеся элементы и заменить их уникальными?

Нередко бывает, что массивы невозможно использовать. Например, если в файле несколько миллиардов чисел, которые надо обработать, то при попытке создания массива получите OutOfMemoryException.
В такой ситуации лучше определить метод следующим образом:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

static IEnumerable<int> Random(IEnumerable<int> arr) {
   var s = new HashSet<int>();
   var r = new Random();
   foreach (var iv in arr) {
      var v = iv;
      while (s.Contains(v)) 
         v = r.Next(0, 1000);  // возвращает одно из чисел от 0 до 1000
      s.Add(v);
      yield return v;
   }
}

Random(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 });  // результат: { 1, 2, 3, 458, 781 }
```