# Генерация случайный чисел без повтора

Tags: c#

Подскажите как сгенерировать например 20 случайных чисел, в диапазоне 1-50, без повтора. Через класс Random знаю только чтоб были повторы, можно как-то без них?

Comment: Делаешь цикл на 20 итераций для массива где будут числа лежать. В каждой итерации вызываешь функцию генерации рандомного числа. В этой функции генеришь число и смотришь, если ли оно уже есть в массиве, то перевызываешь эту функцию до тех пор, пока такого числа не окажется в массиве чисел. Если нет, добавляешь в массив

Comment: Данный алгоритм хорош, только пока предел значения во много раз превышает количество необходимых значений. Представляете сколько раз придется генерировать последнее число, если понадобится 20 чисел от 1 до 22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rand = new Random();

var knownNumbers = new HashSet<int>();

var arr = new int[20];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    int newElement;
    do
    {
        newElement = rand.Next(50);
    } while (!knownNumbers.Add(newElement));


    arr[i] = newElement;

    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
}
```

Жутко неэффективно, и будет зацикливаться при значениях диапазона меньше, чем длина массива.

Answer (score 2):

Вы из одного вуза все, да?

Вот вам классический random shuffle.

```
const int n = 20;
int[] perm = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray(); // 0 1 2 ... (n - 1)
// если это НЕ учебное задание, не создавайте новый Random здесь, а заведите
// один глобальный, а то значения будут всегда одни и те же
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = n − 1; i >= 1; i--)
{
   int j = r.Next(i + 1);
   // exchange perm[j] and perm[i]
   int temp = perm[j];
   perm[j] = perm[i];
   perm[i] = temp;
}
```

---

<sub>Код одолжен из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/181206/10105).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой алгоритм:

1. Повторяем 20 раз;
2. A = Случайное число из диапазона [минимум; максимум - количество шагов + номер шага];
3. Ищем A в списке результатов;
4. Если находим повтор, увеличиваем A на единицу и переходим к п 3.;

Comment: Увеличение A на еденицу делает последовательность неслучайной. Если массив достаточно длинный - под конец будут выстреливать "нерандомные" k, k+1 k+2 k+3...

Comment: @PashaPash Вы не поверите, но "наивный" способ дает такие же спецэффекты, только еще и увеличивает количество циклов. Если нужно "правильное" распределение, то придется накладывать на предложенный мной алгоритм сортировку, а потом еще и перемешивать если необходимо

Comment: не поверю. "наивный способ" - код в моем ответе - не дает возрастающие подпоследовательности. вот только что проверил на коде из ответа - там редко выпадают даже два числа, идущие подряд.

Comment: @PashaPash Тогда сортировать с увеличением значений на индекс в массиве и заново мешать

Comment: хотя, проверил, нет последовательностей ни при вашем, ни при "наивном подходе". для целей топикастера скорее всего сойдут оба.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю другой алгоритм: делаем массив из 20 возрастающих чисел от 1 до 50 (без повторов), потом перемешиваем.