# Генерация случайных чисел без повторов

Tags: c++, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Морской бой. Расставление кораблей идет по самому банальному и неэффективному алгоритму: генерация рандомного числа X и Y, проверка можно ли разместить корабль по данным координатам с учетом уже стоящих кораблей, если нельзя, то ищем новые рандомные числа. Я бы не хотел так сильно усложнять алгоритм, но сделать его чуть эффективнее и просто генерировать числа без повторов X и Y, но так, чтобы они брали в обхват всё поле с размером FIELD_SIZE. Т.е. уже не будет повторов и дополнительных ненужных проверок.

```
Randomize();
ShipData SD(Random(FIELD_SIZE), Random(FIELD_SIZE), 0, true);
for (int i = 0; i < SHIPS_COUNT; i++) {
    if (Random(2) == 1)
        Ships[i].SetVertical();

    SD.Length = Ships[i].GetDeckLength();
    SD.Horisontal = Ships[i].isHorisontal();

    while (!CanPlaceShip(SD)) {
        Randomize();
        SD.X = Random(FIELD_SIZE);
        SD.Y = Random(FIELD_SIZE);
    }

    PlaceShip(SD);

    Ships[i].SetX(SD.X);
    Ships[i].SetY(SD.Y);
}
return true;
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Случайных чисел без повторов не бывает, бывает случайное подмножество заранее заданного множества.

Comment: Смотрите сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/181206/10105 (Вам нужно пронумеровать все поля, и брать не всю последовательность, а только её начало.)

Comment: И даже не повторение XY не гарантирует, что корабля еще нет, он же может занимать несколько клеток, а генератор может соседние координаты выдать

Comment: @Mike: Это я понимаю. Просто не хочу запариваться с исключением координат уже поставленных кораблей (включая координаты палубы, ведь может она быть длинной в 4 клетки)

Comment: Я не уверен конечно, но скорее всего все таки использование рандомных чисел из всего множества целых чисел - не самый лучший вариант. Я бы на Вашем месте создал матрицу, как двумерный массив размерности `FIELD_SIZE` типа int, приравнял бы циклом ее всю к 0, после, уже от туда брал любое доступное(рандомное) значение, проверял какие клетки рядом == 0 (т.е. пустые) и дальше уже расставлял корабли, автоматически заполняя единицами те места, где будет стоять корабль, ну и + его контур разумеется.

Comment: @whalemare: у меня уже есть готовый класс CField, который содержит двумерный вектор из ячеек, где отмечены все состояния  NOT_PLACED = -1, NOT_AVAILABLE = 0, PLACED_SHIP = 1, WRECKED_SHIP = 2, MISS = 3, AROUND_SHIP = 4 на этом строится вся логика игры, а метод CanPlacedShip, как раз проверяет можно ли поставить корабль

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот пример генерации чисел без повторов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> x(10); // вектор из десяти элементов

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        x[i] = i; // инициализация диапозоном от 0 до 10 (здесь вы можете указать свой диапозон)
    }

    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(x.begin(), x.end()); // перемешиваеаем

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << x[i] << endl; // вывод
    }

    return 0;
}
```

возможный вывод:

```
3
9
1
4
5
2
0
8
6
7
```

подсказка: вместо чисел можно задать диапазон координат

---

**Обновил ответ**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    struct srt{
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    vector<srt> v;
    srt s;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            s.x = i;
            s.y = j;
            v.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end()); // перемешиваеаем

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            cout << v[i].x << "\t" << v[i].y << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А можно ли подобное только для обхода поля 10 на 10? Т.е. 100 вариантов 0,0; 0,1; 1, 0; ...

Comment: Смотри обновленный ответ

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, конкретный пример будет полезным. `FIELD_SIZE`, насколько я понимаю - это число клеток по горизонтали/вертикали. Тогда алгоритм делится на 2 части:

1. Заполняем карту ходов из `FIELD_SIZE * FIELD_SIZE` значений
2. Перебираем все `FIELD_SIZE * FIELD_SIZE` значений и выбираем на каждой итерации случайный номер поля, исключая его из последовательности

[пример:](https://ideone.com/wiLMQN)

```
size_t id, i, x, y;
std::vector<int>v(FIELD_SIZE * FIELD_SIZE);
//  заполняем выборку ходов
for(i = v.size() ; i-- ; v[i] = i);
//  перемешиваем выборку
for(i = v.size() ; i-- ; ){
  id = int(double(i) * rand() / RAND_MAX + .5);
  //  v[id] - случайный ход, без повторов
  y = v[id] / FIELD_SIZE;
  x = v[id] % FIELD_SIZE;
  printf( "turn (%i, %i)\r\n", (int)x, (int)y);
  //  удаляем ход из выборки
  std::swap(v[i], v[id]);
}
```

Если нужно продолжить ходы, то повторно заполнять выборку уже не надо, карта ходов после всех итераций просто перемешана и ее можно снова подать на повторную игру.

Answer (score 2):

Есть смысл завести дополнительный вектор `IField` (переменной размерности) с координатами разрешённых полей основного массива, а к состояниям существующего вектора добавить индекс `CField.IND`для доступа к этому полю в `IField`.
Исключение поля из индексного массива с учётом перекрёстной индексации проводить так:

1. Записать последний элемент вектора `IField` на место удаляемого.
2. Изменить индекс соответствующего элемента в `CField`.
3. Уменьшить размерность `IField` на 1.

Если вектор `IField` поддерживается в состоянии без пропусков, рандомный выбор свободных полей не потребует повторов.