# Заполнить массив 100000 элементами и перемешать

Tags: c#

Как создать элемент массива с 100000 элементами а потом его перемешать, что бы числа не шли по порядку? Random не подходит.

Comment: Что означает «Random не подходит»?

Comment: Что значит "что бы числа не шли по порядку"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот классический Кнутовский shuffle:

```
static Random random = new Random();

// ...

const int n = 10000;
int[] perm = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray(); // 0 1 2 ... (n - 1)
for (int i = n − 1; i >= 1; i--)
{
   int j = random.Next(i + 1);
   // exchange perm[j] and perm[i]
   int temp = perm[j];
   perm[j] = perm[i];
   perm[i] = temp;
}
```

---

<sub>(Код одолжил из [своего же ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/181206/10105).)</sub>

Comment: Решение с en so `perm.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next());`

Comment: @pavel: OrderBy хочет стабильные индексы, а для `rnd.Next` это не гарантировано. Так что мне решение с OrderBy кажется подозрительным. Ну и к тому же `rnd.Next`'ы могут повторяться.

Comment: То что повторяются не критично, а по поводу лямбды, спасибо, я думал сначала все генерируется потом сортировка, а не "влет"

Comment: @pavel: Ну, количество вызовов лямбды не гарантировано документацией, поэтому я бы на него не закладывался.

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен, что подойдет, но этот метод позволит перемешать заполненый масив, тип данных можешь поменять.

```
String[] randomnWords(String[] strings) {
            int el = strings.length;
            int r;
            Random rand = new Random();
            String[] str = new String[el];
            boolean[] b = new boolean[el];

            for (int i = 0; i < el; i++)
                b[i] = true;


            for (int i = 0; i < el; i++)

                if (b[r = rand.nextInt(el)]) {

                    b[r] = false;
                    str[r] = strings[i];

                } else {
                    while (--r >= 0) {
                        if (b[r]) {
                            b[r] = false;
                            str[r] = strings[i];
                            break;
                        }
                        if (r - 1 < 0)
                            r = el - 1;
                    }
                }


            return str;
        }
```

Возможно этот метод слишком много итераций будет задействовать, но лучше ничего не придумал.