# Рандомная генерация со списком исключений

Tags: c#

Всем привет, вообщем такая задача есть

```
List<int> lisin = new List<int>();
```

В нём есть числа 6, 32, 45, 65

Как сделать чтобы при генерации

```
Random.Range(0, 120);
```

Не как не моли получится числа которые в list, плюс нужно чтобы рядом стоящие тоже не могли получится то есть вот эти числа не могли вообще получится:

4, 5, **6**, 7, 8 и 30, 31, **32**, 33, 34 и , 43, 44, **45**, 46, 47 и 63, 64, **65**, 66, 67

Comment: 1) Создать список из 120 элементов 2) Удалить из него те 4, что не должны появиться. Получим список из 116 элементов. 3) Генерировать случ число от 0 до 115 - брать соответствующий индекс в списке

Comment: @tym32167 ВладД [рекомендовал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/181206/213987) тасование Фишера — Йетса так что можно создать прямо числа по порядку, выкинуть ненужные - а потом перетасовать.

Comment: @AK согласен, мне просто лень было искать ответ Влада :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-простому:

```
public class RandomWithExcluding
{
    public RandomWithExcluding(Random random, int min, int max, int[] excludes)
    {
        this.Random = random;
        this.Min = min;
        this.Max = max;
        this.Excludes = excludes;
    }

    public Random Random { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int[] Excludes { get; set; }

    public int Get()
    {
        var result = this.Random.Next(this.Min, this.Max);

        if(this.Excludes.Any(x => x == result))
            return this.Get();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
void Main()
{
    var generator = new RandomWithExcluding(new Random(), 1, 120, new int[] {6, 32, 45, 65} );
    for(var i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(generator.Get());
    }
}
```

Можно и одной функцией написать, а не в класс выносить:

```
void Main()
{
    var random = new Random();
    for(var i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetRandomWithExcluding(random, 1, 120, new int[] {6, 32, 45, 65}));
    }
}

public int GetRandomWithExcluding(Random random, int min, int max, int[] excludes)
{
    var result = random.Next(min, max);

    if (excludes.Any(x => x == result))
        return this.GetRandomWithExcluding(random, min, max, excludes);

    return result;
}
```

Ну и помним, что Random.Next() включает нижнюю границу, но не включает верхнюю.

Comment: `excludes.Any(x => x == result)` => `excludes.Contains(result)`

Comment: @АндрейNOP  Да, верно, linq тут особо-то и не нужен.