# Рандом без повторения C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы выдавалось определённое количество рандомных чисел, только сделать это таким образом, чтобы если например уже выпадало число 2, и оно выпало заново, в таком случае нужно сделать другое рандомное число, и делать его до того момента, пока оно не будет отличаться от всех которые уже были сгенерированы.

Comment: В каком диапазоне нужны рандомные числа?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/181206, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547996

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F  И кстати, это будут уже не совсем случайные числа :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сделать генератор,  в котором  условие проверяет, есть ли такое число в нём.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можно хранить уже выбранные числа в множестве.

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <optional>

#include <iostream>

struct RandomGenerator {
    RandomGenerator(): gen(rd()), count(static_cast<unsigned long long>(gen.max() - gen.min()) + 1) { } // count - сколько уникальных чисел можем мы получить

    std::optional<unsigned int> generate() {
        unsigned int generatedNumber = gen();
        if(history.find(generatedNumber) != history.end()) {
            if(history.size() == count) { // Если мы уже сгенерировали все числа, то возвращаем nullopt
                return std::nullopt;   
            }
            return this->generate(); // Если это число уже выбиралось рандомом, то идем выбирать число по-новой
        }
        history.insert(generatedNumber); // Иначе добавляем в список уже выбранных чисел
        return std::optional(generatedNumber); // И возвращаем его
    }
private:
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen;
    
    unsigned long long count;
    std::set<int> history;
};

int main() {
    RandomGenerator generator;
    while(true) {
        if(auto number = generator.generate(); number.has_value()) {
            std::cout << number.value();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Данный код не предусматривает никаких диапазонов для генерации случайных чисел, если же они нужны,то его следует изменить следующим образом:

```
template<unsigned int MIN_, unsigned int MAX_>
struct RandomGenerator {
    const static unsigned int MIN = MIN_; // Минимальное число, которое может выпасть
    const static int MAX = MAX_; // Максимальное число, которое может выпасть
    
    RandomGenerator(): gen(rd()), distribution(RandomGenerator::MIN, RandomGenerator::MAX), count(static_cast<int>(MAX_ - MIN_) + 1) { }

    unsigned int generate() {
        unsigned int generatedNumber = distribution(gen);
        // ...
    }
private:
    // ...
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution;
};

int main() {
    RandomGenerator<1, 5> generator;
    while(true) {
        if(auto number = generator.generate(); number.has_value()) { // Пока есть еще числа, которые мы уже не сгенерировали, генерируем их
            std::cout << number.value();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Возможный вывод:

```
24531
```

Comment: а не дорого ли сет для такого действия?

Comment: @Maggot, Если диапазон небольшой - еще нормально, но чем его можно заменить, как вы думаете? Кроме как unordered_set

Comment: смотрите не только на асимптотику но и на размер структуры